# What's the purpose of an empty loop on PyTorch DataLoader?

Tags: python, pytorch

I came across with the following code:

```
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torchvision.transforms import ToTensor, Lambda

annotation_file = 'Your csv file path here'
img_dir = 'Your image file directory path here'
transform = ToTensor()
target_transform = Lambda(lambda y: torch.zeros(10, dtype=torch.float).scatter_(0, torch.tensor(y), value=1))

dataset = FashionMNISTDataset(annotation_file, img_dir, transform=transform, target_transform=target_transform)
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset)

for idx, example in enumerate(dataloader):
    pass
```

I'm interested to understand the purpose of the last part:

```
for idx, example in enumerate(dataloader):
    pass
```

It iterates over the dataloader but does not do anything inside the loop. What's the purpose of that loop? I saw that same idea in a few different places.

Comment: If you found the code in some documentation somewhere, considering the value is labelled as `example`, one can assume it is an example on how you can use `enumerate` on the dataset. It's likely just a [stub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_stub).

Comment: If that's the case then `pass` is just a placeholder that you would replace with your actual code that processes each element of the dataset.